# python: opencv comparing histograms wird results

Tags: python, opencv, comparison, histogram

I'm using builtin `opencv` function to open image, remove background, crop image, and then calculate histogram of file, to compare it with histogram of different file.

To compare histograms I'm using BGR color space with function:
`cv2.compareHist(hist_1, hist_2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)`

My code is

```
def cv_histogram(image, channels=[0, 1, 2], hist_size=[10, 10, 10], hist_range=[0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256], hist_type='BGR'):
    #convert to different color space if needed
    if hist_type=='HSV':    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    elif hist_type=='GRAY': image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    elif hist_type=='RGB':  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    image_hist = cv2.calcHist([image], channels, None, hist_size, hist_range)
    image_hist = cv2.normalize(image_hist, image_hist).flatten()
    return image_hist

def cv_compare_images_histogram(img_base, img_compare, method='correlation'):
    hist_1 = cv_histogram(img_base)
    hist_2 = cv_histogram(img_compare)

    if method == "intersection":
        comparison = cv2.compareHist(hist_1, hist_2, cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT)
    else:
        comparison = cv2.compareHist(hist_1, hist_2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
    return comparison

im1 = image_remove_background(cv2.imread("1.jpg"), bg_lower_bgr, bg_upper_bgr)
im2 = image_remove_background(cv2.imread("2.jpg"), bg_lower_bgr, bg_upper_bgr)
sim = cv_compare_images_histogram(im1, im2)
img_new = image_stack(im1, im2)
cv2.imshow('img_new', img_new)
print("Histogram similarity is: ", sim)
```

as on screen below, images have different colors/objects, but I receive very high correlation: 0.9198019904818888
[image]

Script works perfect for most of files, any idea WHY so wired results?

Comment: Please, proof-read your post and fix the indentation of your source code sample. (I guess some kind soul did it for you while I wrote it).

Answer (score 0):

After creating visual histograms for those two images and investigating more, the problem was, after removing background (replacing with black pixels), there was a huge spike in pixels with pitchblack color [0,0,0] which with bin size-10, resulted in very high correlation.

To resolve issue I had to create histograms without black pixels, by removing them from histogram range: `hist_range=[1, 256, 1, 256, 1, 256]`

Comment: did you instead try to compute the histogram of gray-scale images and then compare?

Comment: @FäridAlijani to resolve the problem I'v removed "black pixels" from the calculation